# Javascript: Assigning objects to const variables vs let variables

Tags: javascript, constants

This might be a silly question, but I wanted to see if there were any best practices in terms of what to assign to a CONST or LET variable. I understand CONST variables cannot be reassigned once declared, but I noticed that by assigning an object to a CONST variable, you can update the contents of the object.

```
const person = {
  name: "John"
}
console.log(person.name) => //"John"

person.name = "Kim"
console.log(person.name) => //"Kim"
```

Would this be considered bad practice? If not, why not use LET variable?

Comment: `Would this be considered bad practice?`  No, .. `why not use LET variable` because your not reassigning a new object to person, your modifying a property of an object.

Comment: `const myHome = new House();` is a `House` object that I live in. If `myHouse` is a const, that only stops me from moving to a new house; it does not stop me from knocking down walls, opening windows, or moving furniture around inside my `House`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example isn't bad practice, and is perfectly acceptable because `person` still refers to the same object, even though you've changed a property. You could add, remove or change properties and `person` still refers to your object.

ES6 `const` makes the binding immutable, not the value.

In ES6 you should use `const` if you don't need to rebind, otherwise use `let`. In your example you are not rebinding `person` so it is valid and correct.

If for example you had a second object `person2` and tried to rebind like `person = person2` then that would throw a type error.

If you wish to make your object value immutable, you can do that with [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) like so:

```
const person = Object.freeze({
    name: "John"
});
person.name = "Kim";
// quietly fails or throws a type error
```